# Changing the default extension when creating a new text file in Windows 10

Tags: windows, file, windows-10

When you `Right click -> New -> New Text Document`, the file comes up with this name: `New Text Document.txt` and the name part comes as *selected* so you can type a different name. But to change the extension part you need to go to the right of the `.` and then press `delete` multiple times. I want the default extension to come up as `.rtf`. And it would be pretty interesting to change the `"New Text Document"` to a reminder like *"Create backup"*

*Why do I want to do this?* I save my notes in `rtf` format where I can do simple formatting which is not supported by `txt` files. I don't want to use `docx` files since they open in `Word` which takes some time to open. I only use them when I'm writing a story or something. I like the simple interface of `wordpad` for notetaking and so I've set the `rtf` files to open in `wordpad` as default. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new rich text file directly, which will give you the extension .rtf

`Right click -> New -> Rich Text Format`

Comment: I don't see any option for "Rich text document" after clicking new

Comment: What OS are you using, I have win 10(version 1903).

Comment: I am using windows 10 (2018 edition). Command prompt shows this version: [Version 10.0.17134.885] I didn't update it, i don't have internet to download any large updates. But even if it already is an option, what I actually want to do is change it to any extension or any name.